# Orleans frontend other that ASP.NET

Tags: .net, orleans

As far as i could find, the only possible frontend for Orleans it is ASP.NET. Is there any way to have not .net frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The api specification is public, you can implement in the language that you prefer, But as it relies in .net binary serialization and primitives, I don't think is a wise decision. If you want to connect from other languages, the prefered approach it's to use a webapi as a proxy between the orleans cluster and the rest of your services. There is even a automatic API which publishes all orleans public methods as http endpoint in the contributions packages.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am want to communicate with Orleans over http from other services. The simplest solution is to make simple front-end with ASP.NET and communicate through it.

Comment: Well, https://github.com/OrleansContrib/OrleansHttp is an automatic bridge between http and your orleans cluster. It's a bit outdated, but maybe its helpful as a starting point.